# three.js how to change axis position of a cube

Tags: javascript, three.js, voxel

I am currently working on a project with three.js (voxel painter). I encounter a problem when I change the size of a cube the xyz axis remains centered on the cube and does not place at the extreme left of the cube, which gets a shift of the cube when it is placed on the grid

```
   cubegeo= new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 50, 70)
```

What I want

[image]

By default on three.js

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can apply matrix to the cubegeo:

```
cubegeo.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(cubeWidth/2, cubeHeight/2, cubeLength/2) );
```

Comment: This is now preferred: `cubegeo.translate( cubeWidth / 2, cubeHeight / 2, cubeLength / 2 );`